# Executing Sql Server Stored Procedure

Tags: php, sql-server

My PHP skills are rusty. I am trying to execute a stored procedure with the following code

```
<?php

    $server = “SQLINSTANCE”;
    $options = array(  "UID" => “uname”,  "PWD" => “password,  "Database" => "HomeSensors");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $options);
    if ($conn === false) 
    die("<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));

    echo "Successfully connected!<br/>";

    $stmt = mssql_init('addSensorData', $conn);


    mssql_bind($stmt, '@Pool',    90,  SQLINT1,     false,  false,  3);
    mssql_bind($stmt, '@Temp',    80,  SQLINT1,     false,  false,  3);

    $proc_result = mssql_execute($stmt);

    if( $proc_result === false) {

        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }

    mssql_free_statement($stmt);


    ?>
```

When I execute the following, the server response is:

```
Successfully connected!
```

But nothing is executed and I don't see any errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [`sqlsrv_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) is from [Microsoft SQL Server Driver for PHP (SQLSRV)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php); [`mssql_execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-execute.php) seems to be from [another PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php), which seems to be deprecated ("This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mssql_connect` at first.
What kind of result does your procedure have to return(one or many result sets)?
Also try `mssql_query` instead of `mssql_init` function.
Approximate approach:

```
$result = mssql_query("addSensorData Var1, Var2, Var3...");
$arr = mssql_fetch_row($result);
```